# How to fetch live data from website into JSON file?

Tags: json, web-scraping

I would like to fetch live data from http://www.emojitracker.com/
For example, I would like the first emoji it's data at the time that my script searches for it (with an interval time) and display that on my website. I would like to display that into something like this: http://www.pubnub.com/blog/fun-with-d3js-data-visualization-eye-candy-with-streaming-json/

Any tips for creating data visualisations?

Answer (score 0):

Data is already coming in JSON format on this URL: http://www.emojitracker.com/api/rankings